# Convert columnar data to multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, what formula can I use to convert columnar data to multiple rows, with a "group" in column A?

[image]

Comment: I think that TRANSPOSE is what you want. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
={tocol({A3:A14,A3:A14}),tocol(B3:C14)}
```

Comment: Perfect solution - thank you. :)